# jQuery timer start the time by manually time then continue from its time

Tags: jquery, timer

I'm using this [jquerytimer](https://jquerytimer.com/)

```
<div name='timer' class='form-control timer'>00:00:50</div>

<button class='btn btn-success start-timer-btn'>Start</button>
<button class='btn btn-success resume-timer-btn hidden'>Resume</button>
<button class='btn pause-timer-btn hidden'>Pause</button>
```

JS

```
$('.start-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            var a = $('.start-timer-btn');
            a.siblings().removeClass();
            if(a.hasClass('active'))
            {
                $('.timer').timer('pause');

                a.removeClass('active').toggleClass('inactive');
                a.removeClass('active').toggleClass('resume');
            }
            else if(a.hasClass('resume'))
            {
                $('.timer').timer('resume');
                a.removeClass('resume').toggleClass('active');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.timer').timer({
                    editable: true,
                    format: '%H:%M:%S'
                });

                a.removeClass('inactive').toggleClass('active');
            }


            $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
        });

        // Init timer resume
        $('.resume-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            $('.timer').timer('resume');
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
            $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
        });


        // Init timer pause
        $('.pause-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            $('.timer').timer('pause');
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
            $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
        });
```

The function is running OK.

When I click start, then time will start from `00:00:01`.

Now I need to set the time manually, example `00:20:00`, then when I click start it should continue the time `00:20:01`.

The current when I click start, it will reset the time from `00:00:00`.

Comment: the documentation you linked to has the answer - `Start at a particular time` - it's literally the 3rd "howto" on that page

Comment: Specify `seconds: 1200` in the options.